# how to new line text in a text block from c# in windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a string that can be of different lengths. This string is then displayed in a Textblock which has a certain amount of width.

```
<TextBlock  Foreground="White"   Margin="660,50,0,0" x:Name="clinicianComment"  FontSize="20" MaxWidth="400"/>
```

How do I get my string to newline should the text reach the max width of my textblock?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `TextWrapping` property to `Wrap`:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" ... />
```